# memcpy or memmove between different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, concatenation, memcpy, memmove

I was reading some information about memcpy and memmove, and if I'm not wrong, you can use both for move memory between different arrays.

So here is my question: If I want to concatenate this objects with this method.

```
class List
{
    // Pointer to the beginning.
    int* vector;

    // Number of elements, n >= 0
    int n;

    // Capacity for new elements.
    int capacity;
}

void concatenateList(List* listToConcatenate)
{    
    memmove(this->vector + n, listToConcatenate->vector, (listToConcatenate->n)*sizeof(int));
}
```

So, from `"listToConcatenate->vector"` which is the beggining, we will copy all elements from it with `"(listToConcatenate->n)*sizeof(int))"`, and we will put it at the end of the other array `"this->vector + n"`.

Shouldn't this be correct `list2.listToConcatenate(&list1);`? Assuming, of course, we got enough space.

If it is not, what would be the right way to do it? Could this be done with memcpy?

Thank you.

**Edit**: I think I need to add that this does not work on my program. It doesn't crash, but seems like it does nothing.

Comment: Is it valid to concatenate a list with itself?

Comment: Hm... yes it is, why?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's ok even if `listToConcatenate == this`: no memory overlapping.

Comment: You could use `::memcpy()`.

Comment: You can memcpy a part of an array to another part of the same array, as long as the source range and the destionation range don't overlap.

Comment: @mtk99 with this vector = (int*)realloc(vector, sizeof(int)*(capacity));
And yes, I increase the capacity variable after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake.

Yes, you can do that with memmove but I missed something:

```
void concatenateList(List* listToConcatenate)
{    
    memmove(this->vector + n, listToConcatenate->vector, (listToConcatenate->n)*sizeof(int));
    this->n += listToConcatenate->n; //Mistake here.
};
```

That's why it wasn't printing anything. But yeah, I have memmove a bit clearer now. Thank you all for your answers.